# How do I use HTML Agility Pack to extract text from a specific class?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

For example, I want to extract the first definition from http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=potato . It's raw text, though.

```
                    var html = new HtmlDocument();
                html.LoadHtml(new WebClient().DownloadString("http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=potato"));
                var root = html.DocumentNode;
                var p = root.Descendants()
                    .Where(n => n.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("meaning"))
                    .Single()
                    .Descendants("")
                    .Single();
                var content = p.InnerText;
```

This is the code I use to try and extract the meaning class. This doesn't work at all, though... How do I extract the class from Urban Dictionary?

Comment: You should debug your query and figure out what is wrong - one level of LINQ query at a time. If you can't figure out particular cases - make sure to provide [MCVE] (including minimal data inline in the post).

Answer (score 0):

If you change your code as below it works

```
var html = new HtmlDocument();
html.LoadHtml(new WebClient().DownloadString("http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=potato"));
var root = html.DocumentNode;
var p = root.SelectNodes("//div[@class='meaning']").First();
var content = p.InnerText;
```

The text I'm using in `SelectNodes` is [XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) and means all `div` elements with class named `meaning`. You need to use `First` or `FirstOrDefault` as the page contains multiple `div` elements with that class name, so `Single` would throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use, if you wanted to use the same "style" as the link you were using.

```
var p = root.Descendants()
    .Where(n => n.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("meaning"))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Though Tone's answer is more elegant, one liners are usually better.